# IllegalMonitorStateException inside synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime-error, illegalmonitorstateexcep

Though I have written wait inside synchronized block. I am getting `IllegalMonitorStateException`. What's the reason then?

```java
package trials;

public class WaitNotifyTrial {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Generator g=new Generator();
        g.start();
        System.out.println("Start");
        synchronized (g) {
                try {
                    g.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Printing exception");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(g.value);
        }
    }
}

class Generator extends Thread{

    int value;

    public void run(){
        synchronized (this) {
            value=10;
        }
        notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your error is not from `notify();` which is outside of `synchronized(this)` block. which means your thread doesn't possess monitor of `Generator`?

Comment: show the full stacktrace

Comment: yes..was doing mistake..after putting notify() inside synchronized block,exception got resolved :) thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

These are some of the things wrong with your code:

- you call `notify()` outside of `synchronized (this)` (this is your immediate problem);
- you don't use the proper *wait-loop* idiom, thus risking nondeterministic behavior/deadlocks in the face of *spurious wakeups* and *missed notifications*;
- you use the `wait-notify` mechanism on a `Thread` instance, which is [recommended against in its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long,%20int%29);
- you extend `Thread` instead of using that class as-is and only passing it an instance of your implementation of `Runnable`.

For almost a whole decade now, the general advice has been to avoid the `wait-notify` mechanism altogether and instead use one of synchronization aids from `java.util.concurrent`, such as the `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: can you elaborate regarding number 3? why is it bad to use wait \notify on thread instance?

Comment: @axelrod I thought the link to the official documentation was enough. What piece of the puzzle are you still missing?

Comment: Not sure what could possibly break \ not work as expected if i'll use it this way

Comment: All threads waiting on a thread instance will be notified when that thread ends. Also, each time `notify` is executed on that instance, all threads executing `join` on the thread will be notified. Neither of these may actually break anything in your code. However, since there is never any *need* to wait/notify on a thread instance, it is a non-issue to avoid it.